# Is there a better way to debug a SOAP request?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, soap, web-applications

At the moment I'm confronted with the following situation:

- I use a web app in my browser that runs on an app server (`appsrv`).
- Depending on configurations I set in the web app (XML and XSLT) `appsrv` sends a SOAP request to a web service (`web_service`) on an other server (`websvcsrv`).
- If something goes wrong and I want to check what's sent in the SOAP request I have to do the following:

  1. Change a line in `web.config` on `appsrv` from:

  ```
  <add key="WebServiceUrl_{web_service name}"
      value="https://websvcsrv/path/to/web/service.asmx" />
  ```

  to

  ```xml
  <add key="WebServiceUrl_{web_service name}"
      value=http://{server which exists and accepts http but has otherwise
          absolutely nothing to with the web app or the web service (dummy) }" />
  ```

  This is only to change from `https` to the unencrypted `http`. See below for why this is necessary.

  2. Run Wireshark on `appsrv` and start capturing.
  3. Run the web app in my browser to a point where the SOAP request is sent from `appsrv` to the `web_service` on `websvcsrv`, where the latter two refer to `dummy` now.
  4. Ignore the error that's shown by `appsrv` in the browser (since just `dummy` is behind now).
  5. Switch to Wireshark on `appsrv`, filter for `xml`, find the SOAP request and look at its XML. (This is where `http` comes into play, since with encrypted `https` one can't see anything useful for human eyes.)
  6. Correct possible errors in the web app config.
  7. Undo 1., i.e. change line in `web.config` from `dummy` to `websvcsrv`.
  8. Try the corrections with the real `web_service` on the real `websvcsrv`.
  9. If something still goes wrong re-start at 1. If not, continue at 10.
  10. Enhance the configuration.
  11. Run the web app in my browser to a point where the–now enhanced–SOAP request is sent from `appsrv` to the `web_service` on `websvcsrv`.
  12. If something goes wrong start at 1.

Needless to say that this is amongst the craziest things I've ever experienced in my decades of developing.

Is there a better way to debug this?

Comment: Are the "websvcsrv" and the "appsrv" in a production environment or could you hook up a Debugger like Visual Studio? (Do you even have the Source?) Where is the error happening? Is it a coding error or a config error?

Comment: @MindSwipe Both are in a test env. I do not have access to any source apart from XML/XSLT I configure in the web app from which the SOAP request is created. The error happens in the `web_service` on `websvcsrv` if the SOAP request isn't correct, e.g. due to XML tag or attribute name typos, improper tag content or attribute values (e.g. supplying a letter if a number is expected), missing tags or attributes and the like.